# Multiple Update panel : How to know which one triggered the postback

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know which UpdatePanel causes the partial PostBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851694/how-to-know-which-updatepanel-causes-the-partial-postback)

In case of multiple update panels on page how to know which update panel triggered the post back.

Answer (score 0):

if You know where have you put update panels then you will be aware about that portions and if you/user rise any server side event in that particular area then only that particular area will be refreshed.