# Figuring out if an UpdatePanel was triggered from within or without

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have a user control that includes an updatepanel. That contorl is placed inside an updatepanel on the webpage. 
Is there a way to determine in the user control, if the postback was triggered by a contorl inside it or by a control on the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851694/determine-which-updatepanel-causes-the-partial-asynchronous-postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to figure it out.
I created a session variable flag, which I turn on when an event of a control inside my user control is triggered. on PreRender I check its state and turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a label within the update panel and if the control triggers (if it's a button, on button click change the label text) then you can have the label change when the control is tiggered.

Hope that helps.